# Vue: Unable to call component multiple times with different parameters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api

I am trying to call the same component multiple times using different parameters. I have two objects, and depending on the type supplied I want to show a text input or numeric input. If I call it once it works fine, but calling with different parameters does not show two components on the screen.

*Main Program*

```
<script setup>
import TestForm from '../components/TestForm.vue';

const testObject1 = {
  type: 'string',
  value: 'test',
};
const testObject2 = {
  type: 'numeric',
  value: 5,
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <form>
      <TestForm :testProps="testObject1"></TestForm>
      <TestForm :testProps="testObject2"></TestForm>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

*Component (TestForm.vue)*

```
<!-- eslint-disable vue/no-setup-props-destructure -->
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';

const newValue = ref('');

const props = defineProps(['testProps']);
newValue.value = props.testProps.value;
const getType = computed(() => props.testProps.type);
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <input v-if="getType === 'string'" type="text" v-model="newValue" />
    <input v-if="getType === 'number'" type="number" v-model="newValue" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Your `v-if` checks for `number` but `testObject2.type` is `numeric`. Since there is no `else` the component has nothing to render except the `<div>`

Comment: Thanks just missed it and looking for issues with parameter passing...

Answer (score 1):

As @Moritz suggested, you have a typo in your second object: `'numeric'` should be `'number'`. Change that and you're good to go.

---

However, I wanted to point out you could also rely on `typeof value` ***<sup>1</sup>***.

See it here:

```js
const { createApp, defineComponent, computed, ref } = Vue;

const items = [
  {
    label: "first",
    value: "two",
  },
  {
    label: "second",
    value: 2,
  },
  {
    label: "third",
    value: 0,
  },
  {
    label: "fourth",
    value: "3",
  },
  {
    label: "fifth",
    value: "",
  },
  {
    label: "sixth",
    value: null,
  },
  {
    label: "seventh"
  }
];

createApp({
  setup: () => ({ items }),
})
  .component(
    "my-input",
    defineComponent({
      template: `
  <div>
    <label>{{ label }}:
      <input :type="isText ? 'text' : 'number'"
             :placeholder="isText ? 'type a text' : 'type a number'"
             v-model="localValue">
    </label>
  </div>
  `,
      props: ["value", "label"],
      setup: (props) => ({
        isText: computed(() => typeof props.value === "string"),
        localValue: ref(props.value),
      }),
    })
  )
  .mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js
"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-input v-for="(item, key) in items" :key="key" v-bind="item" />
</div>
```

---

<sup>***1***</sup> - Please notice this solution is brittle. When there is no value, you'll need to pass missing string values as empty string and treat the other falsey values as numbers.